# How to erase blue i information in r studio. (package: GGally)

Tags: r, package, r-markdown, scatter-plot

When I use GGally package the error(?) comes out.

For example when I run below chunck, the graph shows well but some printing comment also comes out.

````
```{r, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
# Scatter matrix
ggpairs(liver, columns=1:6) +
  labs(title = "Scatter matrix of chemicals")
```
````

[image: output]

I cannot find any ways to delete this output part.
Are there any ways to erase above plot: [m,n] [======] n% est: _s part?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Try `ggpairs(liver, columns=1:6, progress=FALSE)`